# What should a JSON service return on failure / error

Tags: jquery, web-services, json

I'm writing a JSON service in C# (.ashx file). On a successful request to the service I return some JSON data. If the request fails, either because an exception was thrown (e.g. database timeout) or because the request was wrong in some way (e.g. an ID that doesn't exist in the database was given as an argument) how should the service respond? What HTTP status codes are sensible, and should I return any data, if any?

I'm anticipating that service will mainly be called from jQuery using the jQuery.form plugin, does jQuery or this plugin have any default way of handling an error response?

**EDIT:** I've decided I'll use jQuery + .ashx + HTTP [status codes] on success I'll return JSON but on error I'll return a string, as it appears that that is what the error option for jQuery.ajax expects.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The HTTP status code you return should depend on the type of error that has occurred. If an ID doesn't exist in the database, return a 404; if a user doesn't have enough privileges to make that Ajax call, return a 403; if the database times out before being able to find the record, return a 500 (server error).

jQuery automatically detects such error codes, and runs the callback function that you define in your Ajax call. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Short example of a `$.ajax` error callback:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/some/resource',
  success: function(data, textStatus) {
    // Handle success
  },
  error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: What error code do you think I should return if someone supplies invalid data, like a string where an integer was required? or an invalid email address?

Comment: something in the 500 range, same as any similar server side code error

Comment: The 500 range is a server error, but nothing has gone wrong on the server. They made a bad request, so shouldn't it be in the 400 range?

Comment: what makes you think something didn't go wrong on the server? The OP mentions database timeouts as an example reason. If you provided bad data to an aspx page you'd not be surprised by a 500. This is logically the same.

Comment: As a user if I recieve a 500 I know I'm not to blame, if I recieve a 400 I can work out what I have done wrong, this is particularly important when writing a API, as your users are technically literate and a 400 tells them to use the API correctly. PS - I agree that a DB timeout should be a 500.

Comment: Just want to point out that 404 means *the addressed resource* is missing. In this case, the resource is your POST processor, not some random thing in your DB with an id. In this case 400 is more appropriate.

Comment: @thatismatt, I loved your comment.

Answer (score 57):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574035/how-to-handle-db-constraint-violations-in-the-user-interface) for some insight into best-practices for your situation.

The topline suggestion (from said link) is to standardize a response structure (for both success and failure) that your handler looks for, catching all Exceptions at the server layer and converting them to the same structure. For example (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574035/how-to-handle-db-constraint-violations-in-the-user-interface/575092#575092)):

```
{
    success:false,
    general_message:"You have reached your max number of Foos for the day",
    errors: {
        last_name:"This field is required",
        mrn:"Either SSN or MRN must be entered",
        zipcode:"996852 is not in Bernalillo county. Only Bernalillo residents are eligible"
    }
}
```

This is the approach stackoverflow uses (in case you were wondering how others do this kind of thing); write operations like voting have `"Success"` and `"Message"` fields, regardless of if the vote was allowed or not:

```
{ Success:true, NewScore:1, Message:"", LastVoteTypeId:3 }
```

As [@Phil.H pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674027/what-should-a-json-service-return-on-failure-error#674046), you should be consistent in whatever you choose. This is easier said than done (as is everything in development!).

For example, if you submit comments too quickly on SO, instead of being consistent and returning

```
{ Success: false, Message: "Can only comment once every blah..." }
```

SO will throw a server exception (`HTTP 500`) and catch it in their `error` callback.

As much as it "feels right" to use jQuery + `.ashx` + HTTP [status codes] IMO it will add more complexity to your client-side code base than it's worth. Realize that jQuery does not "detect" error codes but rather the lack of a success code. This is an important distinction when trying to design a client around http response codes with jQuery. You only get two choices (was it a "success" or "error"?), which you have to branch further on your own. If you have a small number of WebServices driving a small number of pages then it might be okay, but anything larger scale may get messy.

It's much more natural in a `.asmx` WebService (or WCF for that matter) to return a custom object than to customize the HTTP status code. Plus you get the JSON serialization for free.

Comment: Valid approach, just one nitpick: examples are not valid JSON (missing double quotes for key names)

Comment: this is what I used to do, but you really should be using http status codes, that's what they're there for (especially if you're doing RESTful stuff)

Comment: I think this approach is definitely valid - http status codes are useful doing restful stuff, but not so helpful when, say, you're making api calls to a script that houses a database query. Even when the database query returns an error, the http status code will still be 200.

In this case, I typically use the 'success' key to indicate if the MySQL query has been successful or not :)

Answer (score 17):

Using HTTP status codes would be a RESTful way to do it, but that would suggest you make the rest of the interface RESTful using resource URIs and so on.

In truth, define the interface as you like (return an error object, for example, detailing the property with the error, and a chunk of HTML that explains it, etc), but once you've decided on something that works in a prototype, be ruthlessly consistent.

Comment: I like what you are suggesting, I'm assuming that you think I should return JSON then? Something like: { error: {message: "An Error Occurred", details: "It occurred because it is Monday."}}

Comment: @thatismatt — That's quite reasonable, if errors are always fatal. For more granularity, making `error` a (possibly-empty) array and adding a `fatal_error: bool` parameter will give you quite a bit of flexibility.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for when-to-use and when-not-to-use RESTful responses. :-)

Comment: Ron DeVera has explained what I was thinking!

Answer (score 3):

I think if you just bubble an exception, it should be handled in the [jQuery callback that is passed in for the 'error' option](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).  (We also log this exception on the server side to a central log).  No special HTTP error code required, but I'm curious to see what other folks do, too.

This is what I do, but that's just my $.02

If you are going to be RESTful and return error codes, try to stick to the standard codes set forth by the W3C: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 3):

I've spend some hours solving this problem. My solution is based on the following wishes/requirements:

- Don't have repetitive boilerplate error handling code in all JSON controller actions.
- Preserve HTTP (error) status codes. Why? Because higher level concerns should not affect lower level implementation.
- Be able to get JSON data when an error/exception occur on the server. Why? Because I might want rich error information. E.g. error message, domain specific error status code, stack trace (in debug/development environment).
- Ease of use client side - preferable using jQuery.

I create a HandleErrorAttribute (see code comments for explanation of the details). A few details including "usings" has been left out, so the code might not compile. I add the filter to the global filters during application initialization in Global.asax.cs like this:

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new UnikHandleErrorAttribute());
```

Attribute:

```
namespace Foo
{
  using System;
  using System.Diagnostics;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Net;
  using System.Reflection;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.Mvc;

  /// <summary>
  /// Generel error handler attribute for Foo MVC solutions.
  /// It handles uncaught exceptions from controller actions.
  /// It outputs trace information.
  /// If custom errors are enabled then the following is performed:
  /// <ul>
  ///   <li>If the controller action return type is <see cref="JsonResult"/> then a <see cref="JsonResult"/> object with a <c>message</c> property is returned.
  ///       If the exception is of type <see cref="MySpecialExceptionWithUserMessage"/> it's message will be used as the <see cref="JsonResult"/> <c>message</c> property value.
  ///       Otherwise a localized resource text will be used.</li>
  /// </ul>
  /// Otherwise the exception will pass through unhandled.
  /// </summary>
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public sealed class FooHandleErrorAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
  {
    private readonly TraceSource _TraceSource;

    /// <summary>
    /// <paramref name="traceSource"/> must not be null.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="traceSource"></param>
    public FooHandleErrorAttribute(TraceSource traceSource)
    {
      if (traceSource == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(@"traceSource");
      _TraceSource = traceSource;
    }

    public TraceSource TraceSource
    {
      get
      {
        return _TraceSource;
      }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor.
    /// </summary>
    public FooHandleErrorAttribute()
    {
      var className = typeof(FooHandleErrorAttribute).FullName ?? typeof(FooHandleErrorAttribute).Name;
      _TraceSource = new TraceSource(className);
    }

    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
      var actionMethodInfo = GetControllerAction(filterContext.Exception);
      // It's probably an error if we cannot find a controller action. But, hey, what should we do about it here?
      if(actionMethodInfo == null) return;

      var controllerName = filterContext.Controller.GetType().FullName; // filterContext.RouteData.Values[@"controller"];
      var actionName = actionMethodInfo.Name; // filterContext.RouteData.Values[@"action"];

      // Log the exception to the trace source
      var traceMessage = string.Format(@"Unhandled exception from {0}.{1} handled in {2}. Exception: {3}", controllerName, actionName, typeof(FooHandleErrorAttribute).FullName, filterContext.Exception);
      _TraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Error, TraceEventId.UnhandledException, traceMessage);

      // Don't modify result if custom errors not enabled
      //if (!filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
      //  return;

      // We only handle actions with return type of JsonResult - I don't use AjaxRequestExtensions.IsAjaxRequest() because ajax requests does NOT imply JSON result.
      // (The downside is that you cannot just specify the return type as ActionResult - however I don't consider this a bad thing)
      if (actionMethodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(JsonResult)) return;

      // Handle JsonResult action exception by creating a useful JSON object which can be used client side
      // Only provide error message if we have an MySpecialExceptionWithUserMessage.
      var jsonMessage = FooHandleErrorAttributeResources.Error_Occured;
      if (filterContext.Exception is MySpecialExceptionWithUserMessage) jsonMessage = filterContext.Exception.Message;
      filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
        {
          Data = new
            {
              message = jsonMessage,
              // Only include stacktrace information in development environment
              stacktrace = MyEnvironmentHelper.IsDebugging ? filterContext.Exception.StackTrace : null
            },
          // Allow JSON get requests because we are already using this approach. However, we should consider avoiding this habit.
          JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
        };

      // Exception is now (being) handled - set the HTTP error status code and prevent caching! Otherwise you'll get an HTTP 200 status code and running the risc of the browser caching the result.
      filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError; // Consider using more error status codes depending on the type of exception
      filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

      // Call the overrided method
      base.OnException(filterContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Does anybody know a better way to obtain the controller action method info?
    /// See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770303/how-to-find-in-which-controller-action-an-error-occurred.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="exception"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static MethodInfo GetControllerAction(Exception exception)
    {
      var stackTrace = new StackTrace(exception);
      var frames = stackTrace.GetFrames();
      if(frames == null) return null;
      var frame = frames.FirstOrDefault(f => typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(f.GetMethod().DeclaringType));
      if (frame == null) return null;
      var actionMethod = frame.GetMethod();
      return actionMethod as MethodInfo;
    }
  }
}
```

I've developed the following jQuery plugin for client side ease of use:

```
(function ($, undefined) {
  "using strict";

  $.FooGetJSON = function (url, data, success, error) {
    /// <summary>
    /// **********************************************************
    /// * UNIK GET JSON JQUERY PLUGIN.                           *
    /// **********************************************************
    /// This plugin is a wrapper for jQuery.getJSON.
    /// The reason is that jQuery.getJSON success handler doesn't provides access to the JSON object returned from the url
    /// when a HTTP status code different from 200 is encountered. However, please note that whether there is JSON
    /// data or not depends on the requested service. if there is no JSON data (i.e. response.responseText cannot be
    /// parsed as JSON) then the data parameter will be undefined.
    ///
    /// This plugin solves this problem by providing a new error handler signature which includes a data parameter.
    /// Usage of the plugin is much equal to using the jQuery.getJSON method. Handlers can be added etc. However,
    /// the only way to obtain an error handler with the signature specified below with a JSON data parameter is
    /// to call the plugin with the error handler parameter directly specified in the call to the plugin.
    ///
    /// success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    /// error: function(data, jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
    ///
    /// Example usage:
    ///
    ///   $.FooGetJSON('/foo', { id: 42 }, function(data) { alert('Name :' + data.name); }, function(data) { alert('Error: ' + data.message); });
    /// </summary>

    // Call the ordinary jQuery method
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON(url, data, success);

    // Do the error handler wrapping stuff to provide an error handler with a JSON object - if the response contains JSON object data
    if (typeof error !== "undefined") {
      jqxhr.error(function(response, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        try {
          var json = $.parseJSON(response.responseText);
          error(json, response, textStatus, errorThrown);
        } catch(e) {
          error(undefined, response, textStatus, errorThrown);
        }
      });
    }

    // Return the jQueryXmlHttpResponse object
    return jqxhr;
  };
})(jQuery);
```

What do I get from all this? The final result is that

- None of my controller actions has requirements on HandleErrorAttributes.
- None of my controller actions contains any repetitive boiler plate error handling code.
- I have a single point of error handling code allowing me to easily change logging and other error handling related stuff.
- A simple requirement: Controller actions returning JsonResult's must have return type JsonResult and not some base type like ActionResult. Reason: See code comment in FooHandleErrorAttribute.

Client side example:

```
var success = function(data) {
  alert(data.myjsonobject.foo);
};
var onError = function(data) {
  var message = "Error";
  if(typeof data !== "undefined")
    message += ": " + data.message;
  alert(message);
};
$.FooGetJSON(url, params, onSuccess, onError);
```

Comments are most welcome! I'll probably blog about this solution some day...

Comment: boooo! it's better to have a simple answer with only a necessary explanation than a huge answer for the sake of satisfying a specific situation. go for a general answer next time, so everyone can use it

Answer (score 2):

I would definitely return a 500 error with a JSON object describing the error condition, similar to [how an ASP.NET AJAX "ScriptService" error returns](http://encosia.com/2009/03/04/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/).  I believe this is fairly standard.  It's definitely nice to have that consistency when handling potentially unexpected error conditions.

Aside, why not just use the built in functionality in .NET, if you're writing it in C#?  WCF and ASMX services make it easy to serialize data as JSON, without reinventing the wheel.

Comment: I don't think that 500 error code should be used in this context. Based on the specification: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html, the best alternative is to send a 400 (bad request). 500 error is more suitable to an unhandled exception.

Answer (score 2):

Rails scaffolds use `422 Unprocessable Entity` for these kinds of errors. See [RFC 4918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4918#section-11.2) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you should use HTTP status codes. And also preferably return error descriptions in a somewhat standardized JSON format, like [Nottingham’s proposal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-nottingham-http-problem), see [apigility Error Reporting](https://apigility.org/documentation/api-primer/error-reporting):

> The payload of an API Problem has the following structure:
>
> - **type**: a URL to a document describing the error condition (optional, and "about:blank" is
>   assumed if none is provided; should resolve to a *human-readable* document; Apigility always
>   provides this).
> - **title**: a brief title for the error condition (required; and should be the same for every
>   problem of the same **type**; Apigility always provides this).
> - **status**: the HTTP status code for the current request (optional; Apigility always provides this).
> - **detail**: error details specific to this request (optional; Apigility requires it for each
>   problem).
> - **instance**: URI identifying the specific instance of this problem (optional; Apigility currently
>   does not provide this).

Answer (score 1):

If the user supplies invalid data, it should definitely be a `400 Bad Request` (*The request contains bad syntax or cannot be fulfilled.*)

Comment: ANY of the 400 range is acceptable and 422 is the best option for data that can't be processed

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be returning any http error codes, rather custom exceptions that are useful to the client end of the application so the interface knows what had actually occurred.  I wouldn't try and mask real issues with 404 error codes or something to that nature.

Comment: Are you suggesting I return a 200 even if something goes wrong? What do you mean "custom exception"? Do you mean a piece of JSON describing the error?

Comment: Blah, returning http code doesn't mean you could not ALSO return error description message. Returning 200 would be rather silly not to mention wrong.

Comment: Agreed with @StaxMan - always return the best status code but include the description in the returning info

Answer (score 0):

For server/protocol errors I would try to be as REST/HTTP as possible (Compare this with you typing in URL's in your browser):

- a non existing item is called (/persons/{non-existing-id-here}). Return a 404.
- an unexpected error on the server (code bug) occured. Return a 500.
- the client user is not authorised to get the resource. Return a 401.

For domain/business logic specific errors I would say the protocol is used in the right way and there's no server internal error, so respond with an error JSON/XML object or whatever you prefer to describe your data with (Compare this with you filling in forms on a website):

- a user wants to change its account name but the user did not yet verify its account by clicking a link in an email which was sent to the user. Return {"error":"Account not verified"} or whatever.
- a user wants to order a book, but the book was sold (state changed in DB) and can't be ordered anymore. Return {"error":"Book already sold"}.