# Extend the exception thrown from ASP.NET when calling a Webservice from JQuery

Tags: asp.net, jquery, web-services, json, exception

I'm using JQuery to load controls dynamically in an ASP.NET development environment using JSON and WebServices. Within this solution I have a business logic layer which has a built in validation mechanism (i.e. validating properties and business rules similar to that of CSLA)

When requesting a new control to be loaded dynamically using JQuery and an ASP.NET WebService, I would like to validate the input from the current control against the business logic validation mechanism (i.e. server side validation) and notify the user if there was any problems.

I managed to achieve this, however, when validation fails in the web service I would like to throw a customer exception containing the validation field id's and associated error messages.

In JQuery, I test for this specific ExceptionType and would like to apply the error messages dynamically to the controls listed in the exception type properties. This is where my problem comes in. Even though I created a custom exception with custom properties the exception that is passed to JQuery in JSON format from the WebService is still a standard exception with none of the additional properties listed. I could simply create a JSON formatted string of values in the exception's message property but would ultimately prefer something a little more elegant. Does anyone know how you can override the serialized exception created by ASP.NET for situations such as this...

Thank you in advance...

G

Comment: I would love to know the answer to this too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into something very similar a couple days ago - basically there's no way to make ASP.NET generate custom exceptions. This is [by design](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=290881), since returning a specific type of exceptions would

> [...] expose implementation
>   details/bugs to the clients. We could
>   do something with special exception
>   type that we let pass through, but its
>   too late for this release [...]

[You could always return different HTTP status codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674027/what-should-a-json-service-return-on-failure-error), and have the browser handle them as custom exceptions - for example, a 500 error would mean one thing, a 401 something else, etc. I think the best solution is to make your method return a string with the exception stack - not elegant, but at least this way the client has all the exception details.

Dave Ward also has info on [ASP.NET AJAX service errors](http://encosia.com/2009/03/04/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/).

Comment: Thanks Gabriel... That really helps me out... G

Comment: FYI all, got a 'dodgy page' block when I went to the Dave Ward link.

Comment: Huh, interesting - I did too. That's a bummer.