# Adding Exception Information on ASP.NET WebMethods called by JQuery Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, exception, webmethod

I am using ASP.NET WebMethods that are called by jQuery / ajax in JSON Format.

I have to improve the exception handling by providing more information for the user.

I catch the original exception and I throw an "UserFriendlyException" where only a "Headline" and "Description" is set.

I only get a very basic JSON String
{"Message":"There was an error processing the request.","StackTrace":"","ExceptionType":""}

I was looking for some solutions and found pages like:
http://encosia.com/use-jquery-to-catch-and-display-aspnet-ajax-service-errors/ or https://stackoverflow.com/a/891442/1099519

where you could access the message, which is fine, but still I wanted to access multiple properties. Most of the articles I've seen usually recommend to use the statusCode for an "ID" more than less.

I thought of a different approch: Propably there is a way, to override the rendering of exceptions in someway (like it is possible in WCF to modify the complete message), so in this case I could catch somehow my UserException and render a JSON string by my very own?

Any ideas?

Thanks for help,
Dominik

Comment: Can you clarify what you meant by " but still I wanted to access multiple properties." - if you are catching exceptions and rethrowing them as a user-defined exception type, you already have full control over the properties of that custom exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually solved it in a very different way. 
I couldn't add any more information to the exception, so I needed to find another solution:

I created a JsonException which I simply can pass an "JsonContainer" Object and when calling ToString(), I escape the properties in the JsonContainer to a Json String.

So in the end, the message of the Exception was a Json-String containing all the information I wanted and i could parse it in JQuery like this:

```
if (data.responseJSON && data.responseJSON.ExceptionType == "InhouseWKOIT.Framework.BusinessEntities.Web.JsonContainerException") {
  var messageObject = JSON.parse(data.responseJSON.Message);
  var someInformation = messageObject.MyProperty1;
  var someMoreInformation = messageObject.MoreInformation;
}
```

This works pretty fine, nice & smoothly :-)

The browser only needs to support the JSON.parse method (either natively or using a plugin)

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the error exception for the class object, as a param in the WebMethod object you return.

This is a jquery method we use to call web method

```
   this.Execute = function (HandlerName, Method, JsonData, SuccessCallBack, ShowLoading, LoaderText, AsyncMode,       ErrorCallback)
    {
        return this.Post(serviceLocation.format(HandlerName, Method), JsonData, SuccessCallBack, ShowLoading, LoaderText, AsyncMode, ErrorCallback)
    };
```

The, when we process the service, if an error has occurred, we just pass the exception message as the result. Hopefully this is what you are looking for. So basically, don't use Jquery Message, but instead send back the return object as an object with the code behind exception that was throwm.