# How to handle a exception thrown in c# by a javascript web app?

Tags: c#, javascript, exception

I'm developing a web application with a client side build with html5 and javascript using, overall, dojo framework (I'm using xhr.post function to communicate with server). The server side is an asmx service in c#.

Here comes the problem: when a webmethod of my service throws an exception:

```
        try
        {
            throw new Exception("TEST");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
            // TODO: send some info to the client about the error
        }
```

the client is realized than an error has occured and fires the error callback function:

```
        deferred = xhr.post({
            url: that.config.urlService,
            handleAs: that.config.handleAs,
            contentType: that.config.contentType,
            postData: that.config.parameters
        });

        deferred.then(function (res) {
            that.success(res);
        },
            function (err) {
                 if (that.config.callbackFail) {
                     that.config.callbackFail(err, that.config.parameters);
                 }
            }
        );
```

But in the 'err' paramater I don't have the exception info, I have the message:

> 'NetworkError: 500 Internal Server Error - http:/.../Services/Applications/Metrawa/ServiceManagement/WSJob.asmx/Filter'

and inspecting the call to server with firebug, in the response tab I can see strange characters, like if the exception hasn't been serialized.

What I want is to get the exception info in javascript. I've searched some info about this, like to create an own serializable exception class, but it doesn´t work neither. Any solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may opt to handle the exception in your server-side code and send it back as JSON, XML or even String--i.e. something your client can understand.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for your answer. I have thought in that option but it would force me to change the return type of the webmethods that have complex objects. Of course, in the worst case I've thought solve my problem by that way but...really is impossible to treat c# exceptions in javascript?

Comment: @christiansr85 .Net exceptions from your server can't be understood by your client-side script. The default way they can communicate is by HTTP error codes like the one you are seeing. Refer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1401099/catching-exceptions-thrown-from-a-c-sharp-web-service-in-javascript) why using JSON might be a smart idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would catch the exception server side and always return a valid object with a "Result" property:

eg res.Result  (as "OK" or "ERR" etc and handle that on the client)