# How to find in which controller/action an error occurred?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I'm logging all errors occuring in my OnException method.

How to find in which controller/action an error occurred?

Comment: Does the ExceptionContext not contain the data you want?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check the exception's call stack.

For example:

```
var actionMethod = new StackTrace(exception)
    .GetFrames().FirstOrDefault(f => 
        typeof(IController).IsAssignableFrom(f.GetMethod().DeclaringType)
    ).GetMethod();
```

Comment: Don't do this; the ExceptionContext provides a much simpler, cleaner, and efficient way to access the controller name and action as per OdeToCode's answer below.

Comment: @ChristopherKing: As long as you have that context available.

Comment: Which I believe he does, as per the statement that he is handling the errors in the OnException method.

Comment: Maybe it's not the most efficient way of doing it in this particular case (context available) but it adds a value to the accepted answer showing another way of doing it. I wouldn't vote it up but I wouldn't down vote it either.

Answer (score 69):

As Charlino implied, the values are available from the ExceptionContext parameter:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    var controllerName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
    var actionName = filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"];

    // ...

    base.OnException(filterContext);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Add the following method in your global.asax and put a break point on it

```
public void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }
```

No matter where in the application an error occurs, the break point on this method will be hit. From here you can see the value for the following expression in the quick watch window and you will know what exactly was the cause of the exception that occurred

```
((System.Web.HttpApplication)(sender)).Context.AllErrors
```

This method will help, no matter where the exception occurs in your web application.

Comment: The question indicates that the controller's OnException handler is being used so this is not answering the question.

Comment: So Application_Error can also have two arguments!