# Get Attributes of Action from within HandleErrorAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, error-handling, custom-attributes

I have a custom error Attribute that is located on top of a controller:

```
public class JsonExceptionAttribute : HandleErrorAttribute
    {
        private ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext errorContext)
        {
            if (errorContext.ExceptionHandled) return;
            if (!errorContext.Action.Attributes.ContainsType(typeof(DontLogPathAttribute)) {    // THIS IS PSEUDOCODE
              _log.Error($"Oopsie. {HttpContext.Current.Request.Path}");
            }

        }
    }
```

On Top of my Controller I simply add my attribute:

```
[JsonException]
public class UserController {
  public ActionResult JustAnAction{}

  [DontLogPath]
  public ActionResult SelfService(string myHash, int userId) {}
}
```

I usually log the path of the Api-Call in case of an error. But there are a few Actions where I do not want to do that. These cases have the `DontLogPathAttribute`  (which is just an empty Attribute-class)

In the ExceptionHandling (`OnException`) I want to find out if this Attribute exists. But in the exceptionContext I do not even find a property to determine the current Action.

The line before the Error Log is pure Pseudocode that shows what I am trying to achieve. Can this be done?

(I've seen a few similar questions here in SO, but in those cases it was never an *ExceptionContext* that had to be dealt with.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3135000/728795 - you can actually figure out the action and the controller, it seems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job

```
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext errorContext)
    {
        string actionName = errorContext.RouteData.Values["action"] as string;

        MethodInfo method = errorContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethods()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeclaringType == errorContext.Controller.GetType() 
                            && x.Name == actionName);

        IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes = method.GetCustomAttributes();

        //DoStuff
    }
```

Comment: Do note that if it is possible to put the `DontLogPath` attribute on a controller, that you need to check for that case as well. If the attribute has parameters that can be set, you would also need to determine which attribute takes precedence over the other if both are supplied with different parameters.

Comment: NightOwl888 is right, this is just covering the methods scope, you should cover class scope yourself,

Comment: That's fine for me. I only want to use this attribute on Actions 
In addition: The code is readable enough to be able to modify it if that changes. Thx