# .ajax json return on error

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: api_url+'client/'+client.id+'.json', 
    data: {
        _method: 'delete',
        id: client.id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#delete-client').html('Success');
    },
    error: function(data) {
        $('#delete-client').css('color', 'red');
        $('#delete-client').html('Error');
    }
});
```

On the error: function the jquery would recieve this json object with a 500 header status

```
{"errors":{"code":777,"message":"Method requested does not yet exist","data":[]}}
```

however if I use data.errors.message it doesnt show the error there. It shows a huge object with different events in chromes developer box when I console.log the return object its using

**FIXED**

```
var error = jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);
$('#delete-client').html(error.errors.message);
```

Comment: If the request errors, why would the callback receive anything?

Comment: I would recommend that you put your fix in an answer, so that it's obvious what the correct answer was. I know this is a really old question, but it ranks high on Google....

Answer (score 1):

add : `dataType:"json"`...............

Comment: Chrome still gives me:

Object
abort: function (a){a=a||"abort",p&&p.abort(a),w(0,a);return this}
always: function (){return b.done.apply(b,arguments).fail.apply(this,arguments)}
complete: function (){if(!d){var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);for(g=0,h=c.length;g<h;g++){i=c[g],j=f.type(i),j==="array"?e.done.apply(e,i):j==="function"&&a.push(i)}k&&e.resolveWith(k[0],k[1])}return this}
done: function (){if(!d){var c=arguments,g,h,i,j,k;b&&(k=b,b=0);for(g=0,h=c.length;g<h

Answer (score -4):

Try reading the [`$.ajax` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> `error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` - **Function**
>
> A function to be called
>   if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The `jqXHR`
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type
>   of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one
>   occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are
>   "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error
>   occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status,
>   such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the
>   error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be
>   called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain
>   script and JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.

Check the arguments list. That's not your data. That's a jqXHR object.

---

By definition, if you've successfully retrieved data from the server, you have `succeeded`, not `errored`. Data is data whether it contains the string `"error"` or not.

You should still be using the `success` callback, even though your data is describing an error. Don't send a 500 header.

---

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: api_url+'client/'+client.id+'.json', 
    data: {
        _method: 'delete',
        id: client.id
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if(data.errors) {
            //Server not able to process the request
        }
        else {
            $('#delete-client').html('Success');
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        //AJAX request not completed
        $('#delete-client').css('color', 'red');
        $('#delete-client').html('Error');
    }
});
```

Comment: Partially agree and disagree.

If my API returns anything but a 200 header status then its an error, which is how jQuery is returning it and kicking it to the error method. 

However you are right about the jqXHR.

Comment: @azz0r: I think you have to choose between serving a 500 error, and sending back "error" data. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/674027/102441) might be helpful.

Comment: Im being general, the error code varies (I have a huge list inbuilt). Thanks for the link though, it just confirmed Im doing things correctly.

Comment: @azz0r: No you're not. You should be returning a 4xx error code, not a 5xx, as the fault is the user's for requesting a bad method, not the server's

Comment: jQuery itself goes to the error method when it receives those headers.

Its part of their design.

Comment: @azz0r: jQuery goes to the `error` handler for 4xx and 5xx errors. That's the crux of the issue.

Comment: I wouldnt say thats an issue. My API outputs 4xx or 5xx errors because to the API they are errors and they give the API a chance to output a representative error code and by sending valid json also it gives us a chance to let them know the specifics of the problem.

I do not agree that the error method should only be called if there is a communication issue, thats not its purpose imo

Comment: @azz0r: Either way, the jQuery API is designed in a way that doesn't expect data to be read after an error.