# JQuery AJAX post request raising exception although handled

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, google-chrome

I have a login JSON service that gets username/password.
When I call it via `JQuery 1.10.1` AJAX, and type the correct credentials, it works.  But when I type incorrect credentials, the error function handler IS FIRED AS EXPECTED, but!  jquery still raises an exception that I can see with Chrome/Firefox console:

```
POST http://localhost/services/admin/login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

The (intentional) ajax error was handled! why do I see it as a javascript error??

Thank you.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "../services/admin/login",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'username': username, 'password': password }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    cache: false,
    success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        window.location = "index.html";
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(".errorDiv").html(jqXHR.responseJSON);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post your server side code?

Comment: It's mainly:  `echo json_encode($e->getMessage());`  where $e is the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get in your console is considered by `Chrome` and `Firefox`  as a *network* error, and not a Javascript runtime error.

They will print this message no matter if you handled the error somewhere or not because the purpose of the message is purely informative.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I dont think you are correct because it says it's an error in a specific JS file line: jquery-1.10.1.min.js:6.   Moreover, firefox specificly relates to it as a javascript error

Comment: No, the error actually says that there is a request that has been issued from this particular JS file that failed. The file that is printed is the file from which you are launching the AJAX request.

Comment: Thank you. so how do I avoid such errors in my system? I'm not supposed to see any errors after all my ajax calls when I handle them (even if they return errors)...

Comment: Well the only way for not having any errors in the console is that the server responds with a successfull HTTP return code to your request. That is 1xx, 2xx and 3xx response codes.

Comment: I understand.  but I read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674027/what-should-a-json-service-return-on-failure-error[/link] and returning 4** seems the right way of doing it.  There isn't any site that I know that preforms AJAX calls (even when error occurs)  that posting those console errors.   Moreover I remember dealing with JQuery ajax before and i've never seen these errors.

Comment: The response pointed by your link is totally correct. HTTP responses should be *meaningful* to an HTTP client. However, a 4xx or a 5xx response code are to be considered as an error, either from your side or from the server side. In any case, the browser consider it useful to report this error to the developer as an informative message.

Comment: Moreover, your browser will not only print an error in the console when an AJAX request fails, but also if a resource declared in the HTML or the CSS code is unreachable. You can do the test.

Comment: I can also point you to many websites where I notice various errors or warnings reported by the browser in the console and that are not related to JS runtime issues.

Answer (score 0):

That is just how it works, the Browser has encountered an error in the network stack and is reporting it.  If it is just authentication that you are doing, you should really fire a 401 - Not authorized response on your server, 500 means a full server error.

Also, just as an aside passing credentials back and forth like this is considered an anti-pattern and is not advised.

Comment: Thanks for your advice - I would fire 401 for authentication, but the question really relates not only to the login problem, but to any service on my system - I'm not supposed to see any javascript errors in my console that, so how would I handle errors in AJAX calls using JQuery, that return error 500?