# HTTP service API error message best practise

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

For a error case when calling some HTTP Rest service API, the response is as follows:

```
{
    "statusCode": "400",
    "error": "Bad Request",
    "message": "Can not construct instance of java.math.BigDecimal from String value 'a': not a valid representation\n at [Source: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination$1@2f650e17; line: 1, column: 2] (through reference chain: com.foo.services.dto.request.ItemToUpdate[\"quantity\"])",
    "validation": {
        "source": "PAYLOAD",
        "keys": ["key"]
    },
    "errorIdentifiers": [],
}
```

I am wondering if the `message` field in the response is appropriate. It does reveal certain level of implementation to the end user. Is this considered as

1. no particular problem at all
2. just a bad cosmetic issue that won't cause serious problem, just not readable to end user
3. potential security risk that definitely needs to be fixed

Comment: 4. It *does* reveal TMI about the implementation but it *is* readable and has no particular issue (you passed a character as "quantity" which is invalid for obvious reasons.

Comment: Maybe the API should validate the input values and return like human readable error message only, not implementation details ever (maybe on debug mode). I would go for 3. See more discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674027/what-should-a-json-service-return-on-failure-error). I think that all exceptions/errors should be logged not revealed to outside.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should only log the stacktrace on the server side. IMO it's technical hints (in addition, perhaps the end user even doesn't use Java to interact with your API) and the only thing that interests the end user of your API is that there is here a validation error within the provided data.

Another remark is that you use the status code and statusmessage within your response payload. I think that you don't need to duplicate this since it's already present in the response.

I would suggest an error message like that:

```
{
    "messages": {
        "quantity": "this must be a valid number"
    }
}
```

I use a JSON structure for the field `messages` since there could be several validation errors within the provided data. Note that it's only a suggestion and you could extend this to your exact needs.

Hope it helps.
Thierry